# What should be done about two users suggesting edits at the same time?

Tags: support, edits

This has not been a major issue, but I've had this situation happen more frequently. To illustrate my point, consider the following scenario.

UserA comes along and sees a post that needs editing. As soon as UserA is posting his suggested edit, UserB, who had enough rep to edit the question without a review queue, pretty much does the exact same thing as UserA's edit.

Now that UserB has came along and edited the question, he has made UserA's edit seem trivial, and it is of course rejected.

What if anything should be done about this? If this keeps happing to UserA, then it will make all his edits seem trivial and useless, and he'll probably get banned from being able to edit post.

This may sound like an unrealistic scenario, but I've seen this happen before.

Comment: +1 This happened to me as well, on unix.se. The original suggestion included adding code markup, but the one the reviewers saw was [extremely trivial](https://unix.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/60772) and rightfully rejected. It is somewhat embarrassing to have such a rejection in your public profile.

Comment: I seriously doubt anyone is going to look at your profile and count rejected edits. Just get used to that some of you edits will be rejected, some of your comments get deleted, some of your post downvoted... (Unless you are Jon Skeet :) )

Comment: Ironically I want to edit your question to change **abel** to **able** but I can't because *suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites*.

Comment: +1 this is happened to me too.i don't know is there a solution,but it must need one solution.which is really avoid the efforts of the peoples with small reputation.

Comment: @TimEdwards Ha. Don't worry. I'll edit my question and change the typo. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: This is happening to me enough that it has deterred me from making any edits - it just feels like a waste of time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While this *can* happen (I've personally verified it under controlled conditions), it's quite rare, and the system already tries to avoid it with edit notifications with relatively little latency. One or two rejections after accidentally submitting an effective reversion won't hurt things too much, and the kind of user that gets more than one or two rejections from this is either *spectacularly* unlucky or submitting so many edits that their others can swamp the comparatively few rejections.

So I don't think anything in particular needs to be done by anyone here, except perhaps giving a fresh post a few minutes to settle the initial surge of potential-editor views before trying to edit it. (That's good advice even for 2kers, who can otherwise waste time editing a post that collides with the same sort of edit notifications.)

The way this race condition works specifically is that a user with edit privileges (a ♦ mod, a user with 1k rep on public beta sites or 2k rep on graduated sites, a user with 100 rep for a CW post, or the post owner) has to submit an edit, and then only a short time later (much less than a minute) the suggester has to submit *their* edit from the editing page before the edit notification comes up by websocket.

Answer (score 10):

> What if anything should be done about this?

Nothing.

> If this keeps happing to UserA, then it will make all his edits seem trivial and useless, and he'll probably get banned from being abel to edit post.

This can't happen.

> This may sound like an unrealistic scenario, but believe me, I've seen this happen before.

No, you haven't, because you can't get banned for edits rejected due to conflicting edits.  Either the user wasn't edit banned, or they were edited banned because of edits rejected for reasons other than conflicting edits.

#### See also:

- [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work/76284#76284)
- [Why does the Community ♦ user approve and reject edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184992/why-does-the-community-user-approve-and-reject-edits)

Comment: When I've said I've seen this happen before, I didn't mean that I've seen someone ban like that. I meant I've seen two users suggest edits at the exact same time. I guess what I'm really asking is are there any bad consequences that would happen to UserA. You already said no, so I guess that answers my question. Thanks

Comment: Well sure edits have conflicted.  I'm sure it happens many times a day, probably dozens of times a day.  The idea of edits conflicting isn't unrealistic in the slightest.

Comment: If you change up the chronology a bit (put User B's 2k edit *before* User A's suggestion is submitted), I submit that it *can* happen, and produce essentially the exact situation as in the OP, with probably identical results. Sure, there's a decent chance the edit notification orange bar will come up, but unless I'm mistaken, that's basically just a race condition, so it's *rare*, but not *impossible*.

Comment: @NathanTuggy No, if an edit has been submitted between when you started editing the post and when you submit your edit then it won't let you submit your edit.  So yes, it is impossible.

Comment: @Servy: I just tested it. It did exactly what you said it would not do. It is not only possible, it wasn't even that difficult to get it right on the first try.

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience, UserB's tend not to reject the edit awaiting approval if it does make the post better. In order to mitigate this, **don't make trivial changes**. Try to address all problems within a post, and not just the "easy to see" fixes.

I assume your question was inspired by [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13569197) that you made and yes on the surface this would seem to be one of those cases where someone prefers a different style of code block. Generally, the code highlighting with `backticks` is used to make code stand out within a block of text, where as the indented code blocks are used for code blocks on their own line. Neither of your or the editor's revisions picked up on the fact that it had 3 meta tags added to it which could have been removed also, or that the language could have been removed from the title.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question you are asking is a more global, general question, "What should be done about two users editing something at the same time?"  It is not a matter of someone else doing something about this in my opinion. It is more a matter of simply resolving the situation with your available resources.  In another words, resolving the situation by yourself.  Every system is different, some systems will post up a message advising you that there is someone else also editing.  For example:

[Concurrent Editing and Merging Changes](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/concurrent-editing-and-merging-changes-144719.html)

I do not believe that your situation is an issue with a "software bug".  It is more of the business rules of the system.  In any case, I am sure that you will be able to resolve this situation on your own without any external resources.